# column resize in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, resize

look at this code (couldn't paste it here it doesn't fit)it represent my real app structure:
[mxml source code](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1663633/bug.mxml)

EDIT: the relevant part of the code:

```
     <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
      <mx:HBox width="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" height="100%">  
        <mx:VBox width="100%" verticalScrollPolicy="off" height="100%">
          <mx:DataGrid height="100%" headerHeight="40" width="100%" wordWrap="true">

            <mx:columns>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="serial_number" minWidth="60" 
                width="60" headerText="serial number"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="int_number" minWidth="80"
                width="80"    headerText="int. number"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ext_number" minWidth="200"
                width="200"    headerText="ext. number"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="desc" minWidth="200"
                headerText="description"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="issued_by" minWidth="100"
                 width="100"    headerText="issued by"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contractual_date" minWidth="85"
                width="85"    headerText="contractual date" />
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="file_size" minWidth="60"   
                width="60"    headerText="file size"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="n_sheets" minWidth="60"   
                width="60"    headerText="n. of sheets"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="contains_drawing" minWidth="65"
                width="65"    headerText="contains drawing"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="issue_at_shipment" minWidth="65"
                width="65"     headerText="issue at shipment"/>
              <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="rev_max_int_number" minWidth="65"
                width="65"      headerText="last rev"/>
            </mx:columns>

          </mx:DataGrid>
        </mx:VBox>
      </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>
```

this is the compiled version you can view online:
[compiled swf](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1663633/bug.swf)

now.. resize a bit the window, look at how oddly the colums resize! The behaviour I'd like to obtain is to have all columns fixed except for the description column, for which I haven't speified the width but only the minWidth property.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say to bind the width to the value that you want, that way it wont resize:

```
var mySize:int = 60;
<mx:DataGridColumn width="{mySize}" />
```

Let me know, thanks!

Comment: maxWidth doesn't exist..
the other solution is equivalent to assigning it directly unless I somehow dispatch the mySize var every few millisecs.. and that's not nice!

Comment: well, mySize is binded to the datagridcolumn's width .. so wouldnt it always be looking to mySize to see and emulate its value?

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for future searches: setting `minWidth` on columns added after the (3.5b SDK) DataGrid is added to a display list (aka dynamically added columns) can put the entire grid in a very bad state where the horizontal scroll bar thumb is inaccurately reflecting a wider grid than actually exists.

If one adds columns by pushing column objects (that have .`minWidth` set) to an array and assigning that array to `DataGrid.columns`, the grid acts like it thinks it is wider than it really is:

- it draws itself as wide as possible (ignoring any .right or .width values)
- its horizontal scroll bar thumb is wider than the visible width would indicate
- one cannot scroll to make the right-most columns visible
- what scrolling one can do is very slow

The solution is: don't do that (use the .`minWidth` property, that is).

Cheers